# Section header and landscape-oriented figure on same PDF page

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Inside a knitr-generated PDF, I want to have the section title on the same page as a figure displayed in landscape format.

If I do this

````r
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-06-21'
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
---
# Section title
\begin{landscape}
```{r pressure, out.extra= 'angle=0', echo = F}
plot(pressure)
```
\end{landscape}
````

The plot appears on a different page than "Section title" as \begin{landscape} apparently starts a new page

But if I do this

````r
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-06-21'
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
---
\begin{landscape}
# Section title
```{r pressure, out.extra= 'angle=0', echo = F}
plot(pressure)
```
\end{landscape}
````

I am getting an error message

```r
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.74 #
       Section title 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile sectionTitle.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See sectionTitle.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

Edit: this syntax, leaving empty lines around the section heading, is not working

````r
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-06-21'
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
---
\begin{landscape}

# Section title

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
\end{landscape}
````

Comment: Try leaving empty lines around the Markdown section heading: without the empty lines, Markdown doesn’t try to interpret the `#` as a heading and instead passes it verbatim to the output (= LaTeX, in this case).

Comment: Doesn't work (see edit in original post), or I misunderstood your answer

Comment: You can't mix Markdown into a LaTeX environment (`landscape` in this case), but you can create a LaTeX environment with Markdown: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html (I haven't tried but I guess a fenced `Div` with the class `.landscape` should work)

Answer (score 0):

Just applying Yihui's comment that links to the [bookdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html), to show that it sounds complex but is really easy!

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: '2022-06-21'
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
---

::: {.landscape data-latex=""}

# Section title

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
:::
````